# JavaScript dumping data into a Table

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function

So I'm working on a assignment in which we have been given various tasks to do for a dummy Social Network. Longer story short one of these tasks requires that I use a method already inserted into the base we are working from, which is as follows:

```
function dump(obj) {
var out = '';
var pre = document.createElement('pre');
for (var i in obj) {
    out += i + ": " + obj[i] + "\n";
}
pre.innerHTML = out;
document.body.appendChild(pre)
}
```

This code takes data from an array which holds the names and strengths of relationships between people and then makes them into a nice set of strings. This method is then called up in another javascript file of which it is linked by a main html file to example shown above. Being called as follows:

```
dump(MATRIX);
```

MATRIX being the array in question I was talking about earlier. This then writes out the data as follows:

```
Bob: 1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Clare: 1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0
Gill: 0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0
Abdul: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0
Hugh: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0
Dave: 0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Earl: 0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Fay: 0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
Iris: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1
Jane: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
```

So now my questions how exactly can this be effectively passed or inserted into a table taking into account the fact i cannot change the actual dump function. I have tried addressing MATRIX in various ways such by name which is how each element in the array is defined and by trying to store the dump in another variable but when addressed in both these ways it returns as undefined. So essentially I need the easiest way possible to be to make the dump into a table format which each cell contains one name/number removing the grammar. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just thought I would update this. In the end I scrapped using dump and after quite allot of fiddling around got to this.

```
name[0].innerHTML = "Bob";
for (prop in MATRIX.Bob){
    sets[0][prop].innerHTML = MATRIX.Bob[prop];
}
name[1].innerHTML = "Clare";
for (prop in MATRIX.Clare){
    sets[1][prop].innerHTML = MATRIX.Clare[prop];
}
name[2].innerHTML = "Gill";
for (prop in MATRIX.Gill){
    sets[2][prop].innerHTML = MATRIX.Gill[prop];
}
name[3].innerHTML = "Abdul";
for (prop in MATRIX.Abdul){
    sets[3][prop].innerHTML = MATRIX.Abdul[prop];
}
name[4].innerHTML = "Hugh";
for (prop in MATRIX.Hugh){
    sets[4][prop].innerHTML = MATRIX.Hugh[prop];
}
name[5].innerHTML = "Dave";
for (prop in MATRIX.Dave){
    sets[5][prop].innerHTML = MATRIX.Dave[prop];
}
name[6].innerHTML = "Earl";
for (prop in MATRIX.Earl){
    sets[6][prop].innerHTML = MATRIX.Earl[prop];
}
name[7].innerHTML = "Fay";
for (prop in MATRIX.Fay){
    sets[7][prop].innerHTML = MATRIX.Fay[prop];
}
name[8].innerHTML = "Iris";
for (prop in MATRIX.Iris){
    sets[8][prop].innerHTML = MATRIX.Iris[prop];
}
name[9].innerHTML = "Jane";
for (prop in MATRIX.Jane){
    sets[9][prop].innerHTML = MATRIX.Jane[prop];
}
```

Their are two table arrays here names and sets which is a 2D array. The for loop searches though each persons links in the MATRIX array and fetches the properties. These are then set to the corresponding positions in the table. I know its not exactly an answer to what I was originally looking to do, but its the best way after much trial and error I have found to be able to output the values stored in an array contained within an array in this case MATRIX.nameofperson

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to join that array to be a string:

```
for(key in matrix){
matrix[key]=matrix[key].join("");
}
```

If the comma is part of the string you could replace:

```
for(key in matrix){
matrix[key]=matrix[key].replace(",","");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried replacing commas and spaces with tabs

```
Bob:    1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Clare:  1   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0
Gill:   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
Abdul:  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
Hugh:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0
Dave:   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Earl:   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
Fay:    0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
Iris:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1
Jane:   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

Comment: You see I need to actually put it into a html table. Also i cannot alter the output I need to find a way to take that and get it into a table.